# how to use regular expression in websocket text frame filter in jmeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter, load, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

i have a response
{"server":{"event":"broadcast","broadcastaction":"events","events":[{"cash":0.0,"id":"3","action":"card","cad":"35","score":"3","cadcount":"1"},{"cash":0.0,"id":"0","action":"close","cad":"-1","score":"0","cadcount":"1"},{"cash":0.0,"id":"3","action":"card","cad":"20","score":"13","cadcount":"2"},{"cash":0.0,"id":"0","action":"close","cad":"-1","score":"-5","cadcount":"2"},{"cash":0.0,"id":"0","action":"cad1oen","cad":"48","score":"-5","cadcount":"1"},{"cash":0.0,"id":"0","action":"play","value":"read"}]}}.Here id value changes from 0 to 5

I used {"cash":0.0,"id":("0"|"${id}"),"action":"play" in websocket text frame filter to capture above mentioned reponse.But i got an error "java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition".How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy.

You can use the below regex expression to extract the data you need

```
{"cash":(.+?),"id":"(.+?)","action":"(.+?)","cad":"(.+?)","score":"(.+?)","cadcount":"(.+?)"}
```

Configure Regular Expression Extractor as follows
[image: Regular Expression Extractor Sample Configuration]

This regex will extract the information as follows:

```
extractedData_g1 = cash
extractedData_g2 = id
extractedData_g3 = action
extractedData_g4 = cad
extractedData_g5 = score
extractedData_g6 = cadcount
```

I used https://regexr.com/ to generate this expression and you can refer the below screenshot
[image: Regexr.com Reference]

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) therefore it makes more sense to consider using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which allows executing [Json Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries to get "interesting" data from JSON responses.

In particular your case the relevant Json Path query would be something like:

```
$.server.events[?(@.cash == 0.0 && @.action=='play')].id
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: No i dont want to extract id. For my single request there are multiple responses received from the server.From that multiple response, i want to filter that above mentioned response. So i choose websocket text frame filter

Comment: only after filtering that particular response , we can able to extract the data using json extractor... am i right?? correct me if iam wrong

Comment: In websocket text frame filter i use regular expressions

Comment: "cash":0.0,"id":("0"|"${id}"),"action":"play" after i removed curly braces its working fine thanks for the help